# How can I set the background color for a specific row in my TableView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I want to set the the color for a row in my TableView but am having some difficulties.  I tried

ListView.getChildAt(0).setBackgroudColor()

but it says I have no children.  I do have 5 items but don't know how to say, "Set this item's background color to red"  I want to do this programmatically in any method in my code.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `((TableRow)table.getChildAt(0)).setBackgroudColor();`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably more effort than you'd want to do, but you could make your own custom adapter and set your background for that row in the adapter.

Here is a nice [tutorial](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/03/15/android-%E2%80%93-applying-alternate-row-color-in-listview-with-simpleadapter/) that does it:

Basically in your adapter, you can override getView

```
   @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
      if (position == 0) {
          view.setBackgroundColor(yourColor);
      }
      return view;
    }
```

One advantage to doing this... you can do further customizations to that row to make it stand out.